# How to allow Width="Auto" in a custom WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a custom control based on Expander class:

```
public partial class HideableExpander : Expander
{
    public new double Height
    {
        get
        {
            if (Visibility== System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return base.Height;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Height = value;
        }
    }

    public new double Width
    {
        get
        {
            if (Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return base.Width;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Width = value;
        }
    }

    public new Thickness Margin
    {
        get
        {
            if (Visibility== System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden)
            {
                return new Thickness();
            }
            return base.Margin;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Margin = value;
        }
    }

    public HideableExpander()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Expander
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="leartWPF.HideableExpander"
x:Name="UserControl"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"/>
</Expander>
```

Now, when I'm trying to use it with Width="Auto" property:

```
            <local:HideableExpander Header="{Binding Expander1Name, ElementName=Window}"  Margin="10" Width="Auto" Background="#00F19494" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                <WrapPanel Height="Auto" Margin="0" Width="Auto" >
                      <TextBlock Text="Please, enter the name of this expander:       " VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                      <TextBox Width="150" Text="{Binding Expander1Name, ElementName=Window, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Background="#FFF5EECC"/>  
                </WrapPanel>
            </local:HideableExpander>
```

I get an exception about not being able convert "Auto" to double:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '10' and line position '8'. ---> System.Exception: Auto is not a valid value for Double. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Double.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.ComponentModel.DoubleConverter.FromString(String value, NumberFormatInfo formatInfo)
   at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at leartWPF.App.Main() in d:\Users\menkaur\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\leartWPF\leartWPF\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
```

What should I do to be able to accept Auto as a value?

Comment: So what's wrong with setting Visibility=Collapsed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding following attribute, I think that should help, and of course, "new" to hide parent's Width...

```
[TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(LengthConverter))]
public new double Width
{
  ......your getter and setter
```

// **EDIT**
    per comment: -"what is a getter and setter?"

```
   //getter and setter sample(grabbing them from the question)
    get
    {
        if (Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return base.Width;
    }
    set
    {
        base.Width = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for those of us new to WPF, can you show an example of what's in the getter and setter too; how they use this?

Comment: get/set are accessors to the exposed property, think of them as read/write to some private field in your class. The reason - encapsulation of a private variable, state, control. You don't want users of your class to have direct access to it, maybe you add some logic on them such as parsing, initialization or formatting on the get, or on the same token validation or events on the set. In the question, this was exactly the case, they don't expose, base.Width directly, but with logic that if Window was hidden width was returned as zero. Hope it makes sense...

Comment: I understand the concepts of getters and setters. I was asking for a full example of what what the code inside them would look like for this situation specifically. Note my question was not "What is a getter and setter?". It was "can you show an example of what's in the getter and setter." Which you provided! :) Thanks!

Comment: my bad, missread your question and definitely didn't mean to cause misunderstandings.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [`TypeConverter` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute.aspx) on the property, specifying a [`LengthConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.lengthconverter.aspx) should be used. `Auto` is then converted to `Double.NaN`.

(You can see this being done on the `FrameworkElement` properties [`Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx) and [`Height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height.aspx))